# Return View for InfoWindow after Volley Response - Android

Tags: android, callback, android-volley, infowindow

I want to display a infowindow on google maps. This infowindow should display a user highscore for different routes. The layout file is set but is not getting updated in time, before returning the view. Until now I've used Volley to retrieve data from my database. Its advantage to handle the tasks asynchronously is in this cause a disadvantage.

I've looked at callblack implementations, at future volley requests and had a little play around with thread sleeps. I failed to implement the first and the third approach and I couldn't find an example for a future volley request which is using inputs to communicate with the database. Here is my code to give you a better impression of what I am trying to do:

public class MyInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

```
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View view;

TextView runner_first_name_view;
TextView runner_second_name_view;
TextView runner_third_name_view;

TextView runner_first_time_view;
TextView runner_second_time_view;
TextView runner_third_time_view;

TextView route_average_time_view;
TextView route_length_view;
TextView route_keywords_view;


public MyInfoWindow(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_info_window, null);

    //Initialize route ID, which is saved in marker title
    final String routeID = marker.getTitle();

    //Initialize TextViews
    runner_first_name_view = view.findViewById(R.id.runner_first_name_view);
    runner_second_name_view = view.findViewById(R.id.runner_second_name_view);
    runner_third_name_view = view.findViewById(R.id.runner_third_name_view);

    runner_first_time_view = view.findViewById(R.id.runner_first_time_view);
    runner_second_time_view = view.findViewById(R.id.runner_second_time_view);
    runner_third_time_view = view.findViewById(R.id.runner_third_time_view);

    route_average_time_view = view.findViewById(R.id.route_average_time_view);
    route_length_view = view.findViewById(R.id.route_length_view);
    route_keywords_view = view.findViewById(R.id.route_keywords_view);

    //this is getting updated before returning the view
    route_length_view.setText(marker.getSnippet() + "km");

    //Asynchronous Volley request 
    String server_url = "http://<<ServerIP>>/loadInfoWindowData.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response

                    String[] runner_names = new String[3];
                    String[] runner_times = new String[3];

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        Log.d(TAG, "array converted");


                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            runner_names[i] = jsonObject.getString("user_name");

                            runner_times[i] = jsonObject.getString("user_duration");

                            Log.d(TAG, "Array filled" + i);
                        }


                        //This is not getting updated in time before returning the view.
                        runner_first_name_view.setText(runner_names[0]);
                        runner_first_time_view.setText(runner_times[0]);

                        if (!runner_names[1].equals(null)) {
                            runner_second_name_view.setText(runner_names[1]);
                            runner_second_time_view.setText(runner_times[1]);

                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + runner_names[1] + "; textview 1: " + runner_second_name_view.getText());
                        }
                        if (!runner_names[2].equals(null)) {
                            runner_third_name_view.setText(runner_names[2]);
                            runner_third_time_view.setText(runner_times[2]);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Log.d(TAG, "Process failed");
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error response
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet connection failed. Couldn't load user highscore." + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("routeID", routeID);
            return params;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    return view;
}
```

}

I'm thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

From [the Info Windows documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows):

> **Note**: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map.

Because of this, you need to rework your Volley callback to create a new InfoWindow and show that one, rather than trying to update an existing `InfoWindow`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Do you have any ideas on how to rework the volley callback? Simply calling marker.showInfoWindow() in the Volley response does not solve the problem. Also I can't return the view within the volley code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to get it working. I've implemented an onMarkerClicklistener to my main activity, where I call a method to execute the volley code. My onMarkerClick returns false, so that it follows the default procedure in moving the camera to the marker and calling the infoWinfow.

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MyInfoWindow.initializeHighscore(MainActivity.this, marker);

return false;

}
```

While the volley code is getting executed, my info Window class is initializing the View for the default case without a volley response. After volley finishes his job marker.showInfoWindow(); is called in the volley response to update the infowindow with the data from the data base.

...

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        Log.d(TAG, "array converted");


                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            runner_names[i] = jsonObject.getString("user_name");

                            runner_times[i] = jsonObject.getString("user_duration");

                            Log.d(TAG, "Array filled" + i);
                        }

                        infoWindowCase = 1;

                        marker.showInfoWindow();

                        infoWindowCase = 0;

                        Log.d(TAG, "info window case reset");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Log.d(TAG, "Process failed");

                    }
                }
            },
```

...

hope this helps somebody.